# How adding a jumper switches the power between 5V and 3.3V?

Tags: power-supply, breadboard

Below is a snapshot of [MB102 bread board powersupply](https://www.banggood.com/MB102-Breadboard-Module-Adapter-Shield-3_3V5V-For-Arduino-Board-p-996801.html?gmcCountry=IN&currency=INR&createTmp=1&cur_warehouse=CN&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_elc&utm_content=frank&utm_campaign=pla-ele-in-pc-0428&gclid=Cj0KCQjwof3cBRD9ARIsAP8x70O8vzHNz_X1fB1z9klWjdPxYwJvZic4uWXE2VgV3Drs-vM7LFCkJ0caAn20EALw_wcB) that can provide either \$5V\$ or \$3.3V\$ on either rails. We can switch between 5V and 3.3V by adding a jumper as shown. I'm just wondering how simply adding a jumper switches the voltage value. Any help ?

[image]

Comment: buzz the contacts out. It isn't too hard to imagine that a jumper connects some 5V rail to an output pin on the breadboard...

Comment: Ahh @PlasmaHH do you mean inside the PCB there may exist a 5V rail and a 3.3V rail; and this jumper is simply connecting them to the output ? I think I see how this works. Thank you so much :) If you have time and convert above comment to answer, I'd love to mark it best. Thanks again :)

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not adding a jumper, you're moving the existing jumper to a different position.

Comment: These downvotes are unfair to op. We all started somewhere and undoubtedly asked questions that may be simple to experienced folk. Op is attempting to learn and downvotes for simple questions just dissuade beginners.

Answer (score 13):

The picture below should explain this: -

[image]

Comment: Dang. Duplication of effort or what? Going for breakfast now.

Comment: It's not a surprise LOL

Comment: You both have been life savers to me so many times XD Wish I could mark multiple answers  best!

Comment: You can up vote each one, that's the closest thing.

Answer (score 12):

There are two [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) fixed-voltage regulators on the board (the black SOT-223 packages). The jumper selects one of the two to go to the output.

[image]

Comment: Is there an echo in here?

Comment: Is there an echo in here?